# googleVis Intensity Map Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, googlevis

I'm trying to generate Intensity map with googleVis each time I search a keywork. I have three issues with googleVis :

1. For some reasons, gvisIntensityMap needs two variables ie two tabs in its data frame otherwise it won't display.
2. gvisIntensityMap always open an independent new windows despite the fact the command is put inside a Shiny render. I try lots of combination of render without success.
3. I managed to display the intensity map inside the shiny app but in that case it still open a new windows with a duplicate map. Moreover, it reduces all the font of the shiny app to a tiny size.

here is the code :

```
process_google_data <- function(keyword) {
if (trimws(keyword) != "") {
    #retrieves raw data from google trends
    gtrends_data <-
        gtrends(trimws(keyword), cat = "0", session = session)

    #generates intensity map data for plotting
    top_regions <-
        gtrends_data[5] %>% ldply(., data.frame) %>% .[, 2:3]
    top_regions$Region %<>% toupper
    top_regions %<>% join(y = countries_data,
                          type = "inner",
                          match = "first") %>% .[order(.[2]), c(1, 3, 2)]
    intensity_data <-
        data.frame(country = top_regions[, 2] %>% as.vector,
                   Intensity = top_regions[, 3],
                   empty = rep(NA, NROW(top_regions))) %>% gvisIntensityMap #for some reasons, two tabs are necessary to display the plot


    gtrends_data$trend$start %<>% sub("^(.{8})(?:\\d{2})", "\\101", .)
    gtrends_data <-
        tapply(gtrends_data$trend$hits,
               gtrends_data$trend$start,
               mean) %>% cbind(names(.), .) %>% as.data.frame
    colnames(gtrends_data) <- c("Date", "hits")
    row.names(gtrends_data) <- 1:NROW(gtrends_data)
    gtrends_data[, 2] %<>% as.integer

    return(list(gtrends_data, intensity_data))
}}


 shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
observeEvent(input$search,
             {        
                 # browser()
                 go <- process_google_data(input$keyword)
                 output$intensityPlot <- htmlOutput({ plot(go[[2]], tag ='chart') })
                 go
             })
```

})

Greateful if you can help. Thanks.